# Finding Joint PDF and calculating $P(X_1 \geq X_3)$

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be i.i.d. ∼ $Exp(2)$ with the p.d.f. $f (x) = 2e^{−2x} \space  \{x > 0\}$.

My thoughts are that given the rate parameter is $2  \implies f(x;2)=2e^{−2x}, \space x>0$.

Then we can say that the joint pdf just be the product of their individual pdf $\implies f(x_1 . . . x_3) = f(x_1) * f(x_2) * f(x_3) \implies 8e^{-2(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)}$ with the domain $x_1,x_2,x_3 > 0$

Then to find  $P(X_1 \geq X_3)$, we integrate $8e^{-2(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)}$ WRT $x_3,x_2,x_1$

Is my thought process so far correct on these steps? Thanks!

Comment: Why bother abiut $X_2$? Use the joint pdf $f(x_1,x_3)$ of $X_1$ and $X_3$.

Comment: If they are iid continuous random variables then $P(X_1 \geq X_3)=\frac12$ no matter what the original distribution is

Comment: I see, so would it be sufficient to say that given the rates are the same, the probability that $X_1 \geq X_3$ is 1/2 due to it being memoryless and $X_1 \geq X_3$ is symmetric to $X_3 \geq X_1$? @Henry

Comment: You do not even need memorylessness.  Continuous (so $0$ probability of ties) and i.i.d. so exchangeable with $P(X_1\ge X_3) = P(X_3\ge X_1)$

Comment: Thank you! @Henry